# html2canvas inserting multiple elements to render

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

Can html2canvas send multiple elements (other than document.body)? Say If I wan't to generate an image based on only several elements in a page, and there are several elements that I don't wan't to render.. How can I edit this code?

```
html2canvas( [ document.body] , {
    onrendered: function( canvas ) {
            img = canvas.toDataURL();
            window.open(img);
        }
```

btw, window.open means that I wan't to display the image on a different page, whilst not interfering with the original html data.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the `display: none` style on the elements you want to hide before calling html2canvas and remove this right after, so they won't display in the img.

Comment: it doesn't work because when I put it in display:block it renders all the elements in display:block, as though if the display:none didn't have a use